# Narrow down jQuery results

Tags: jquery, traversal

I've done a search for elements as follows:

```
var names = $('[name="' + name + '"]');
```

how do I go about narrowing that result down further, say for example, search for particular values?

The obvious answer is to do:

```
var names = $('[name="' + name + '"][value="' + value + '"]');
```

however I specifically want to split it into 2 steps.  I looked at find() and has(), however both look within the dom rather than the dom attributes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to complement @Alnitak answer, you can have multiple filters in the same first query, example:

```
$('[name="' + name + '"]')
                         .filter('[value="value1"']).doStuff({})
                         .end() //goes back to '[name="' + name + '"]
                         .filter('[value="value2"']).doStuffTwo({});
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
var names = $('[name="' + name + '"]').filter('[value="' + value + '"]');
```

If you'd rather avoid (potentially unsafe) string concatenation, you can use a filter function instead:

```
$(selector)
.filter(function() {
    return (this.attr('name') === name);
})
.filter(function() {
    return (this.attr('value') === value);
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/ if you want to return to you original results just use .end() which to allow you to chain your calls. $('[name="' + name + '"]).filter('[value="' + value + '"]').end().filter('[value="' + value2 + '"]');

Comment: `.is` returns a boolean if there's a match, not a set of elements.

Comment: @Alistair - wouldn't that give an "or" rather than "and" test for the two attributes?

Comment: @Alnitak sorry my example wasn't very good say you had a list of inputs you want to add a class based on their value  then you could do this. $('[name="' + name + '"]).filter('[value="' + value + '"]').addClass('myExcellantValue').end().filter('[value="' + value2 + '"]').addClass('myTerribleValue');

Comment: good security tips thanks I'll make a note for my future dev work.

Comment: excellent reply, thanks very much.. good tip on the function too, much cleaner